# Is there a folder in my home directory where I should put my scripts so they are available from any directory?

Tags: command-line, bash

Where should I put my script in my home directory so that I can access it from any directory?

I've tried:

```
o@s:~/$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

But it seems there is no /home/user/ path. The thing is that I'd like only my user to have access to it so putting it in another directory than my home folder is not an option. Should I add something like /home/user/scripts/ to my PATH variable? If so, what's the recommended way to do it... Should I put it in my ~/.bashrc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I add `PATH=/home/djeikyb/bin:$PATH` to my `.bashrc`, and keep all my scripts in `~/bin`.

I think $PATH has greater-smaller::left-right precedence, so I put my personal bin folder first. I use a folder called "bin" because all the other program files are in folders called bin. And I even have a couple actual binaries in mine ;p

Don't forget to reload your bashrc to make changes take effect: `$. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Works perfectly. I did PATH=~/bin:$PATH though, a bit cleaner ;)

Comment: The default `~/.profile` already adds `~/bin` to `PATH`, though only if `~/bin` exists when you log in.  And yes, it is read left to right when looking for a command. The first command by the name it is looking for, that it finds, gets executed.

Comment: You don't have to hardcode your username, the following works too: `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"`